# AutoScroll to next div after a pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have a website where the title of the page you are one takes up the entire screen and then the content is below after you scroll. I was wondering if it would be possible to make it automatically scroll smoothly to the next div after maybe half a second on the "title screen". You can see what I am talking about by going on [this page](http://websitescientist.com/contact-us/).

The class name for the content is contactus, but I made a specific class name for the scrolling called scroll-down. This is because I want to use it in a few different areas, same concept each area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, this is something that works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.portfolio-header').height()
    }, 1000);
});
```

Note that we are using `animate()` to smoothly scroll (in a period of `1000` milisecs) and we are also getting the `height` of the previous block `.portfolio-header` in order to know the number of pixels to scroll.

And finally, we wrap all of that in a `.ready()` function to wait for the document to be ready before doing the scroll.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Just one question, could I make it go a little beyond the height of the previous block? Like scroll for maybe another 20 px (something I will have to mess around with to get correct). Also can I let it pause a little more in the beginning or is that a completely different thing that will make everything else much more complicated? NEVER MIND I FIGURED IT OUT! Thanks.